# Prove The Inequality: $\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}\,dx\leq \frac{1}{3}$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, definite-integrals

I have started working on this $\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^5}} \, dx \leq \frac{1}{3}$ by using the fact that $\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^5}} \, dx < \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^5}} \, dx$
But that didn't work.

Comment: $\sqrt{1+x^5}\geq 1$ on the integration range and $\int_{0}^{1}x^2\,dx=1/3$.

Comment: We can also find a lower bound of $\frac{2\sqrt{2}-2}{3}$ because $x^5 \leq x^3$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm glad I did no post the answer that I had in mind, which was much more complex than yours.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^5}} \, dx \le \int_0^1 x^2 \, dx.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt {1+x^5}}\leq x^2$ on $[0,1]$.

now just integrate both side.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) \ge 0$ and
$n, m \ge 0$
then
$\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^n\,dx}{(1+f(x))^m}
\le \int_0^1 x^n\,dx
=\dfrac1{n+1}
$.